# Freeing memory for const char * variable in C++

Tags: c++

I have a variable declared as const char *. I have allocated memory for that using malloc(). After using it, I want to free that memory using free(). But I am not able to do that and it gives me error that "Attempting to write to protected memory". How do I free the memory allocated?

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Comment: Please post code. If you allocated memory with `malloc` (although why would you in C++) then you must deallocate with `free`. If this isn't working there is an error with the detail of what you are doing.

Comment: Post the code but I'm pretty sure you need to find a better way to do it (there's no need for malloc in C++..you should really do it the C++ way)

Comment: This has a `C++` tag. You should not use `malloc()` and `free()` in a C++ program. Also, as [paxdiablo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/3130720#3130720) shows, this works fine unless you do something wrong. For us to see what you do wrong, you need to post code that actually reproduces that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're getting that error then you're doing something wrong and you'll need to post the code so we can figure out what it is. For what it's worth, you *can* free a `const char*` as evidenced in the following code, which compiles and executes perfectly:

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main (void) {
    const char *x = (const char*) malloc (100);
    free ((void*) x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suppose that cast in `free()` is there because the function takes a non-const `void*`? Because `char*` implicitly converts to `void*`. (And `const char*` to `const void*`.) However, storing the result of allocation as `const T*` doesn't make all too much sense anyway, since you can't change the allocated memory that way. And if it was `char*` (not `const char*`), this code would need one less cast. Of course, all this is moot the moment someone uses `malloc()` and `free()` in C++ anyway...

Answer (score 1):

> After using it

Let me guess, is this what you did?

```
const char* p = malloc(12);
p = "hello world";           // problem: memory leak
free(p);                     // problem: trying to free static memory
```

You should replace the second line with `strcpy(p, "hello world");` or something similar to get rid of the problem. But since you did not provide any code, I'm not going to delve any further into this matter.